# How the Nearby and the Proximity google apis sync with the server?

Tags: google-beacon-platform

We know that the BLE are dumb, they just send a bluetooth signals.

If we say we are using `Estimote` or `Kontakt` as a beacons provider, these two companies provide a mobile app to send the data received from the BLE beacon to the server.

I can use the google proximity api to register beacons, if i make a web application to do that or add beacons using postman, how the cloud will contact my beacon ? how can i know the data sent from this beacons if there is no middleware with the google apis and the beacon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cloud does not contact your beacon and the beacons send no data.

The Google Proximity API requires that Google Play Services be installed on the phone.  Such phones will periodically call out to Google servers to find out what beacons in the vicinity have associated data on Google's servers.  Google Play Services will then respond appropriately to the Google Proximity API with the results.

All intelligence exists on the mobile phone and on Google's servers.  The beacon remains a dumb transmitter sending just a unique identifier.

Comment: That's great, i have registered a beacon and i added an attachment, but there is no notifcation found + i am keep getting "Faild to connect. Do you need to push a button on the beacon?", even that i am so close to my estimote beacon, do you have any idea how to fix that ?
Another question, is there any constraint on the number of beacons registered through api ? if i have like an array of beacons and i want to register each beacon of this array. 

The request body takes on json object not an array of data.
`{
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "Fr4Z98nSoW0h
....
}`

Comment: The Beacon Tool app from Google actually has an option to auto-configure your hardware beacons where it *will* try to talk to your beacon using a GATT interface, but most beacons don't support this.  I would configure your beacon according to Estimote instructions and not use the Beacon Tool app for that.   If using the JSON interface, I am unaware of any limit on the array size.